# Run VBS file in the folder protected from the standard user when the user starts Windows

Tags: windows, boot, windows-registry, vbscript

I know that in order to run VBS file on Windows starting, we can create a Windows registry string with the VBS file path under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run`.

But I need a way to run VBS file every time when a standard user starts Windows without any ability for the user to cancel such running for example by removing the file, registry key or somehow else.

I think to place the file in some system folder or the admin user folder to make the file protected from the standard user. But afaik if to create the string under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, the standard user will be able to remove the string in the registry.

So is there a similar way to the `/Run` string, but fully protected from the standard user?

Answer (score 1):

A standard user will not be able to remove anything from the registry.

Running the `regedit` utility requires Administrator permission,
so no problem here.

Comment: A standard user CAN remove a string under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, but CAN'T under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, I've just checked it again.

Comment: Only if you have disabled the UAC. Even running under a admin account, `regedit` asks for a permission to elevate.

Comment: I've just enabled UAC and now `regedit` asks for a permission under admin account, but under user account I can still run `regedit` without any prompt (Win 10 Pro)

Comment: Simply not possible, unless this user account was somehow manipulated. Create another standard user account and check.